# How to reshape a 1-d array into a an array of shape (1,4,5)?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, encoder

I have these vectors :

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,5]
```

and I could like to have this at the end :

```
A = [ [1,0,0,0,0]
      [0,1,0,0,0]
      [0,0,1,0,0]
      [0,0,0,1,0] ]

B = [ [1,0,0,0,0]
      [0,1,0,0,0]
      [0,0,1,0,0]
      [0,0,0,0,1] ]
```

I have been using np.reshape from python this way:

```
A = np.reshape(a,(1,4,1))
B = np.reshape(b,(1,4,1))
```

And it does just partially the job as I have the following result:

```
A = [[1]
     [2]
     [3]
     [4]]

B = [[1]
     [2]
     [3]
     [5]]
```

Ideally I would like something like this:

```
A = np.reshape(a,(1,4,(1,5))
```

but when reading the docs, this is not possible.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You need to consider that every item in the list a is a categorical value ranging from max(a,b)

Comment: It would be more "pythonic" if the values in `a` and `b` assumed 0-based indexing, so 0 is the first column.  Any chance you can make such a change to your code?  (It is not essential, but it would be nice.  It eliminates a subtraction of 1 in the solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, numpy can assign value to multiple indexes on rows/columns in one go, example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: b = [1,2,3,5]
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [3]: zero = np.zeros([4,5])

In [4]: brow, bcol = range(len(b)), np.array(b) -1  # logical transform

In [5]: zero[brow, bcol] = 1

In [6]: zero
Out[6]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: FYI: To get integer arrays, use `zero = np.zeros((4, 5), dtype=int)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not actually a reshape, as you alter the structure of the data.
Make a new array with the shape you want:

```
A = np.zeros(myshape)
B = np.zeros(myshape)
```

and then index those arrays

```
n = 0
for i_a, i_b in zip(a, b):
    A[n, i_a - 1] = 1
    B[n, i_b - 1] = 1
    n += 1
```

The `i_a/i_b - 1` in the assignment is only there to make 1 index the 0th element. This also only works if `a` and `b` have the same length. Make this two loops if they are not the same length.
There might be a more elegant solution but this should get the job done :)